# Can I port libGDx game to Tizen OS?

Tags: libgdx, tizen

Is the way to do that? Some libraries or suggestions?

I haven't found any information about this

Comment: nikoliazekter, you can show my answer if you are interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 ways:

1.[POLARIS App Generator](http://pag.polarismobile.com/main) An Easy way porting Android App to TIZEN.

2.Port libGDX core project to html5 project using Google GWT plugin and than run this project on TIZEN emulator.

[image]